Are there any interesting questions we could ask about GLBSE?
I think it is one of the more interesting questions, yet it hasn't been mentioned here. Can you think of interesting questions to ask regarding GLBSE?

Wouldn't GLBSE be off-topic?   It is an exchange that happens to have shares denominated in Bitcoin but it isn't using Bitcoin technology necessarily.

@StephenGornick - It's primarily Bitcoin, so I consider it on topic.

Well, the basics are always a good place to start: "What is GLBSE", "How do I use GLBSE" etc. It is one of the more interesting topics but unfortunately so few people use it or know about it that most don't even know the questions to ask. I'm sure even posting an intro question or two will spark others to look into it and ask more questions though.

http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/498/what-is-glbse-how-does-one-use-it
